# Why do the two-pronged Shaver Sockets in the UK have two sets of connectors?

Tags: bathroom

In the UK, you can often find two-pronged sockets in bathrooms; the idea of these is that they offer a lower voltage than standard three-pronged sockets, so are safer to use for charging lower-powered devices.

I've noticed that some of these faceplates offer two sets of prongs - one on either side. Interestingly, it's only possible to connect a single device at once - attempting to connect a second doesn't work; it simply won't fit if there is already a plug in the other socket. Does anyone know why these faceplates have two connectors if it's only possible to physically have one charging at a particular time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UK shaver sockets are **not** a lower voltage, but the ones in bathrooms include an isolating transformer and thermal cutout so that neither wire of the shaver has any voltage to earth (so a shock to earth is impossible) and the socket cannot be used for more powerful appliances.

As bathroom shaver sockets include a transformer, it is easy to incorporate an additional tapping to provide a 115 volt outlet for shavers for visitors from 110-120 volt countries.

[image: shaver socket with transformer and two outlets]

The shutter interlocks so only one socket can be used at a time

1. to prevent the transformer being overloaded

but more importantly

2. if two shavers were connected and became faulty it might be possible for a shock to occur from the shaver in one hand to the shaver in the other hand. This could be full 240 volts and a hand-to-hand shock would cross the heart line, and such shocks are much more likely to be fatal.

Some styles of sockets have a single socket outlet and a changeover switch to change the voltage, eg

[image: shaver socket with voltage selector switch]

(note that if both switches are pressed down accidentally, the lower voltage is selected)

Transformer-isolated shaver sockets are the only type of socket allowed in bathrooms in the UK (or at least, within 3 metres of a *bath or shower*, and most British bathrooms aren't big enough to have 'ordinary' sockets far enough away) but shaver sockets *without* transformers can be used in bedrooms and dressing rooms (the 3m distance does not apply to handbasins):

[image: bedroom shaver socket without transformer]

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you - thank you for also taking the time to add alt text to your images; I'm totally blind, and this is a perfect example of why these should be used. Thanks again. :)